# not getting datePicker popup window

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, datepicker

Hi I'm using mvc3 with asp.net

In my view, in the grid i have'select row'(checkbox),startdate(label) and endDate(label) fields

When i click on select row,instead of label, a datepicker should appear so that user can change  the  enddate

I wrote following code in my view

```
 <div class="cell" style="width:auto;"> <input type="checkbox" class="a" id="selected" onclick="Checked()" />
        </div>

      function Checked() {
if (document.getElementById('selected').checked) {
    document.getElementById('edit1').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('edit2').style.display = 'none';

}
else {
    document.getElementById('edit2').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('edit1').style.display = 'none';
}
}
```

and to get datepicker i wrote this

```
  <div class="cell" id="edit2" style="width:auto;">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ExhibEndDate)</div>
        <div class="cell" id="edit1" style="width:auto; display:none;">@Html.Editor("ExhibEndDate")  </div> 



   $(document).ready(function () {
 $('#ExhibEndDate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
  });
```

But i'm unable to get the datepicker
can u help me

Comment: where is your dom node with id: item_Data_candidateportfolo_ExhibEndDate?

Comment: `checked()` isn't triggering the datapicker.  Where does this id come from ? `#item_Data_candidateportfolo_ExhibEndDate`

Comment: Well i'm not sure whether it'll work or not. Try replacing `display:none` with `visibility:hide` and `display:block` with `visibility:visible` everywhere

Comment: @BhuvanRikka :no its not working ....can u tell me any othr sol

Comment: nope..i have a doubt.  are you sure about having one `div` hidden and another visible?

Comment: @BhuvanRikka Hey i got ans ... thnx for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

I used textbox instead of editorfor as follows

```
     @Html.TextBox("Enddate", item.ExhibEndDate, new { @class = "date" })

   $(document).ready(function () {

    $('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
             });
```

Comment: You can use `EditorFor` then `$('.date').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });` will be `$('#Enddate').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });` just FYI

Comment: @GarrettFogerlie using this type i'm getting the datepicker for every textbox in evry row bt the updated date is shown in the first row of my table wen i select more than one row....can u help me out

Comment: You will have to give each text box a unique id, like `EndDate1` `EndDate2` `EndDate3` so on.